Prior Week DAX Issue
I am trying to automate my current and Prior Week calculations for my table. I am having trouble with the Prior Week based measures and I think it is due to some kind of formatting.
The Prior week calculation was working before I automated the Current Week measure, and both Formats are set to Whole Number. One other note when I change Prior Week to 15, for example, all the other measures work fine.
Any Ideas on what I am doing wrong?
I am expecting a number value that can be used in the other measures.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?
